# Android Listener or Callback OpenGL Error

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

Can i got callback/listener from openGL errors?
I need info about that

```
EGL_BAD_ALLOC
```

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: i use libgdx - https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/tree/master/backends/gdx-backend-android/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/android